# geemap: Error displaying widget - model not found

Tags: jupyter-notebook, geemap

I am using Jupyter Lab to try and get a map to display, but I receive

> Error displaying widget: model not found

whenever I try to run this code. It works on the web browser version so I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
import pandas as pd
import ipywidgets
from ipywidgets import widgets
import ipyleaflet
import geemap
import ee

from IPython.display import display

#Import the Data File
csv_file = "GHISA-USA-EO-1-Hyperion-data-of-crops-1g-1430.csv"

#Assign DataFrame (df) and list Column Names (dn)
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, low_memory=False)
dn = (list(df))

Map = geemap.Map()

Map
```